# How to create inner shadow effect on text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to convert a Figma design into code but it has some text that uses an inner-shadow effect

[image]

I tried to style it using plain and clipping the text-shadow CSS property but the result doesn't quite match the design in which the shadow kind of clips/insets the text.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 80px;
 
    text-align: center;
    
    color: #6225E6;
    text-shadow: -6px 0px 0px #D63737;
    background-color: #151717;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>This is some text<h1/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get closer using mask (doesn't work in Firefox)

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0000;
  text-shadow: 
    5px 0  #6225E6,
    0 0  red;
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-clip: text;
          mask-clip: text;
}

body {
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>This is some text<h1/>
```

For better support you can duplicate the text and try like below:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0000;
  text-shadow: 
    5px 0 #6225E6, 
    0 0 red;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  text-shadow: none;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 data-text="This is some text">This is some text</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

This *kind of* works, I guess depending on who is looking at it and what they're interpreting as the shadow versus the fill. The slight blur is me trying to throw the viewer off a bit but unfortunately, it doesn't give you much room to move the shadow either. I think any solution anybody comes up with is going to require some form of optical illusion to make it work.

```css
body {
  background-color: #151717;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 120px;
  background-color: #D63737;
  color: transparent;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #6225E6, 1px 1px 1px #D63737;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>This is some text</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

added this CSS property called [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing)

that makes every letter have some little gap between them, so the shadow doesn't touch the other letters.

```css
letter-spacing: 6px;
```

[image]

> documentation: The letter-spacing CSS property sets the horizontal spacing behavior between text characters. This value is added to the natural spacing between characters while rendering the text. Positive values of letter-spacing causes characters to spread farther apart, while negative values of letter-spacing bring characters closer together.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6225E6;
  text-shadow: -6px 0px 0px #D63737;
  background-color: #151717;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>This is some text</h1>
```

Comment: Its better but it still doesn't solve the problem look at the "i" in the screenshot, its shadow does not exceed or goes past the text while in code it looks like that there are two separate i's one behind another.

Comment: @sedDev I think you can decrease the number, from `-6px` to `-4px` or less, maybe solve that. also the font-weight is different from figma, try use a smaller `font-weight` this seems medium font-weight in css. so change the `<link>` tag to this `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Tried but didn't work. I think some kind of clipping is required here but cant figure how to do it here.

Comment: sorry, I tried to do my best. hope I help you with something at least. I don't know anything about clipping, hope you will find someone who solves the problem of clipping. have a good day!

Comment: @Temani Afif added now an answer. seems literally what you want! good day! problem solved. but the solution isn't working on all browser, but it does the trick :)

Comment: Yup, i'll figure something out.